# Confusion in Proof of Primitive element theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Recently I have started to study field theory at my own. I am having some confusion in the proof of the primitive element theorem.

**Statement of the theorem** : $F$ be an infinite field. $K/F$ be a finite field extension. Then $K/F$ is simple iff there exists finitely many intermediate fields of $K/F$.

**Proof** : $K/F$ is simple extension $\Rightarrow$ $\exists$  $a$ $\in$ $K$ such that $K=F(a)$.

$L$ be any intermediate field, i.e.,  $F$ $\subset$ $L$ $\subset$ $K$.

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $L$ and $F$ respectively. Then $f(x) |g(x)$.

$L'$ be any field generated by $F$ and coefficients of $f(x)$. Then $L'$ $\subset$ $L$ and $f(x)$ is also the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $L'$.

Hence, $[K:L]=deg(f(x))=[K:L']$

Therefore, $[L:L']=1$ $\Rightarrow$ $L=L'$

**Up to this part I have understood.** I am not being able to understand the next argument that is as follows:

*Since $g(x)$ has finitely many distinct monic factors therefore the number of intermediate fields must be finite.*

Please help me to understand this. I also could not figure out, where the fact " $L=L'$ " is being used.

Thank you in advance. It will also be a great help if somebody kindly suggest me some books from where, a beginner like me, can do problems of field extension. I am following the book ***"Fundamentals of Abstrac******t*** ***Algebra"*** by Malik, Mordeson & Sen.

Answer (score 1):

So if $L$ is an intermediate field, then $f(x)|g(x)$. But if $L_2$ is an intermediate field such that $f_2(x)=f(x)$ (where $f_2$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $L_2$), then $L_2=L$ because they both equal to $L'$. So there is an injection from intermediate fields and factors of $g(x)$, so there is only finitely many intermediate field extensions.